# Error Using PHPMailer After New Installation

Tags: php, email, syntax-error, phpmailer

I just downbloaded the PHPMailer zipped file, saved it to my host server and installed / extracted the PHPMailer files. When I added a require statement to use the PHPMailer.php file, I got the following error message:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in D:\InetPub\vhosts\ ******.com\ *********.com\language\PHPMailer\src\PHPMailer.php on line 288

Doesn't this mean that there is an error in the PHPMailer.php file that was downloaded? If yes, is there a corrected file that I can use in its place? Here's the php code that I am trying to run:

```
<?php

ini_set('include_path','D:\inetpub\vhosts\******.com\*********.com\included_files;D:\inetpub\vhosts\******.com\*********.com\referenced_files;D:\inetpub\vhosts\******.com\*********.com\language;D:\inetpub\vhosts\******.com\*********.com\language\PHPMailer;D:\inetpub\vhosts\******.com\*********.com\language\PHPMailer\language;D:\inetpub\vhosts\******.com\*********.com\language\PHPMailer\src');

include("incPHP1.inc");

require 'Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer.php';
require 'SMTP.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);                              // Passing `true` enables exceptions
try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = $mailHost;  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = $mailUser;                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = $mailPassword;                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('*******@rlchealth.com', 'Mailer');
    $mail->addAddress('****@rlchealth.net', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
    $mail->addAddress('*********@rlchealth.com');               // Name is optional
    $mail->addReplyTo('********@rlchealth.com', 'Information');
    $mail->addCC('************@*****.com');
    $mail->addBCC('************r*****l.com');

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}

?>
```

Comment: what is ur php version? and what is there on line 288?

Comment: The answer to your first question is PHP Version 5.3.28.  As for what appears on line 288, this is 3rd party software downloaded from GitHub.  I don't believe that I can legally reprint that code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is of your PHP version i guess u are using php 5.3 and phpMiller is for 5.6.

Please change ur php version and try again.

Comment: I had to change hosting services to get the version of php that I needed without paying an arm and a leg for the upgrade but it started working immediately once I did.